# How to change all the values in a auto increment column in SQLite while copying contents of a table to another?

Tags: sqlite, loops, sql-update, auto-increment, alter

I'm trying to copy the contents of a table to another in SQLite.
But I can't do this because there are primary key values in the first table which are the same as some in the second table.

I tried to change the value of the first element in the second table, and since it is an auto-incrementing column, I expected that the rest of the values might change and start from there onwards instead of 1,2,3.., and understood that I was wrong.
Is there a loop statement or any other way using which I can change all the values in the column(without affecting the rest of the columns in the respective rows) ?
Or is there any other way to copy the contents of the second table to the first table by changing the values of that specific column?

I already tried many things like inserting all except the column in question, etc., but keep getting errors like mismatch in no. of columns, or some other errors.

This is how the create table statements of both tables look like:

```
    CREATE TABLE "table1" ("_id"    INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, "Col2" TEXT NOT NULL,...........)
```

The '_id' is the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Do not inlude `_id`, but include **all** the other columns both in the `INSERT` and the `SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO table2(col2, col3, col4, col5)
SELECT col2, col3,  col4, col5
FROM table1
```

This way you specify which columns to copy from `table1`, so all the rows of `table1` will be copied to `table2` without the `_id` column.
The value of `_id` in table2 will be taken care of by the system since it is `AUTOINCREMENT`.

Comment: I already tried that, but doesn't seem to work. It says the no. of columns doesn't match.

Comment: If you write the same number of columns it will work.

Comment: Sorry, it says something like "Error: Table1 has x columns but entered only x-1 columns".

Comment: You must specify all the columns in both tables except _id. They do have the same number of columns, don't they?

Comment: Yes I already tried that, and they have the same no. of cols.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. Post your actual code